# Twig template_from_string() inside macro

Tags: twig, timber

If `template_from_string` is inside `{% macro ... %}` string is not parsed.
Example of may code:

`example.yaml`

```yaml
items:
    item1: item1
    item2: |
        {{ AI }} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

php function

```php
function AI() {
    return 'AI<span class="ai-tm">&#8482;</span>';
}
```

Timber `function.php`

```php
 // Global $context
 $context['AI'] = AI();
```

Twig

```
{# If outside macro, template_from_string parses ok #}
<pre>dump(include(template_from_string(items.item2)))</pre>

{% macro example_macro(items) %}
   {# items is php array parsed from yaml file
and passed as parameter to macro #}
  {% for item in items %}
    <p>{{ include(template_from_string(item)) }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Results:

```
{# Notices that {{ AI }} isn't parsed #}
<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access global data or macro within macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391819/cant-access-global-data-or-macro-within-macro)

Comment: @DarkBee not exactly. I have the content of an array, but for some reason `include(template_from_string()` doesn't parses it correctly it inside macro.
If it is outside macro, the output is ok.

Comment: Read the answer again, variables are not accessible unless you pass them